# MSDN Microsoft Translator API

Tags: api, mp3, text-to-speech, msdn

I used the PHP script exactly from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512420.aspx) (with my own Id) and it works fine (urlencoding my text!). I can hear my text!
So far, I'm happy, but... the script overwrites my own page, leaving just a  tab for playing the text.
How can I capture the response in an mp3 file, from within this PHP script?

Hope someone can help me out!

Answer (score 0):

Meantime it's OK: 
I removed 
    header('Content-Type: audio/mp3');
And put in place
    $mp3 = $translatorObj->curlRequest($url, $authHeader);
    $file  = md5($text);    // random name
    $file = "audio/" . $file . ".mp3"; 
    file_put_contents($file, $mp3);